# Generating a view programmatically in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, automatic-ref-counting

## Update:

Thanks for all the tips, everyone. The tutorial mentions that a XIB file is provided (which I don't have) so I'm doing something wrong in how I'm creating the the project.

---

I am following Apple's [Core Data Tutorial for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008305-CH1-SW1). This tutorial has not been updated for ARC—apparently for Xcode 4, since it asks to "create a new project using the Window-Based Application template in the iOS section."

Since that option doesn't exist under Xcode 4.4.1, I looked around Stack Overflow and read that I should create an empty application. As per the tutorial instructions, I created no Storyboard or NIB file.

Other than updating the code for ARC (using `strong` in place of `retain` and not implementing the provided `dealloc` method), I'm confident that the code in my project matches that of the tutorial up to the end of the chapter "The Table View Controller." At this point, the tutorial says I should be able to [run the project and get a view](http://cl.ly/image/1r240S2z460b).

Instead, I get a blank, black screen.

Maybe my problem is too vague to solve here, but should I perhaps be using a different project template? Which one?

I have only two classes: a RootViewController and an AppDelegate. AppDelegate imports RootViewController and contains a UIWindow property. Again, there is no Storyboard or NIB in the project.

I can provide any code too if there's someplace specific to look.

Comment: Sounds like you are missing a view. Try self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]; in -(void)loadView{}

Comment: Why not upgrade to a version of Xcode supported by the tutorial?

You are going to run into lots of problems if you're following tutorials but missing out steps you don't understand / won't work with your Xcode version.

Comment: @deanWombourne: Here, it's a question of downgrading, not upgrading.

Comment: oh, wow, you're right - looks like they're behind in their tutorial! Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check if your setup is correct do the following:

1. add a background color to your window

   `self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];`
2. make sure you tell the window to display itself

   `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];`
3. make sure your view controller is the window's `rootViewController`

   `self.window.rootViewController = myViewControllerInstance;`

Comment: Would this go into the RootViewController's `viewDidLoad`? I added an NSLog statement to the start of that function just now and found that the method isn't ever getting called.

Comment: I ask because my `viewDidLoad` seems to implement statements that would accomplish the same kind of tests. I'll add my method above to show you.

Comment: This code should go into your app delegate's `-applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

Answer (score 0):

Choose Single View Application, and uncheck 'Use storyboards" field. The rest should go the same.

Comment: I tried that one initially—it doesn't include an option to include Core Data.

I realize that I could then add that functionality myself, but its absence means that Single View applications aren't merely the iOS 5 version of the Window-Based application of yesteryear.